# Python script in power bi seems to be summing columns for some reason?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi

Hi I am trying to create a visual in power bi using python.

My dataframe looks like this:

DAY    TIME    VISIT

1------2---- 30

1------4-----60

and so on. (Each day is 1-7, Mon-Fri, and Time is 0-23, which is midnight-11pm)

Each column is an integer and I want to plot a 3d surface using matplotlib.

I can run the code no problem outside of power bi and it generates exactly what I want.

```
df = pd.read_csv("plot.csv")
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(df['DAY'], df['TIME'], df['VISIT'], cmap=plt.cm.viridis, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

However when I try to run this in power bi:

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as a preamble for your script: 

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(INDEX, DAY, TIME, VISIT)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(dataset['DAY'], dataset['TIME'], dataset['VISIT'], cmap=plt.cm.viridis, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

I get an error that the x and y arrays must be of length 3. Take a closer look at what seems to be going on it appears the columns are getting summed for some unknown reason. For example dataset['DAY'] will have length 1 and will be just the sum of the values in that column and so it can't possibly plot it.

I have zero idea why it is doing this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to compare data types between df and dataset? For your DF you had `read_csv` which use delimiters.  What type of data do you have for your dataset before sending it to the DataFrame?  (INDEX, DAY, TIME, VISIT) 
compare df.dtypes with the raw values of those variables/lists, and look for delimiters.

Comment: @guardian I just import the data into power bi using power query it looks correct from the table view.

Comment: @guardian They are both saying the same thing, namely: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the d for dype.  
`print(dtype(df['DAY']))`
`print(type(dataset['DAY']))`
`print(type(DAY)) `
Check the differences, when pandas load the data, it may be not loading it like you see.

Comment: Both still seem to be series. I don't know about dtype (it gives an error as it doesn't recognize that function) but yeah all seems to be series.

Comment: Can you provide raw data from the 
`dataset = pandas.DataFrame(INDEX, DAY, TIME, VISIT)` 
I want to see where INDEX, DAY,TIME comes from (file, input, etc.) and see how it comes

Comment: @guardian You were correct. It seemed to be a data issue, I copied the data into PBI directly and now it is working as intended. Thank you.